# Delphi window losing focus after custom drag

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop

I've got this code that moves my Main Window around when I drag around `MyThingThatDragsIt`

```
procedure TMainForm.ApplicationMessage(var Msg: TMsg; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  ScreenPt : TPoint;
  DragControl : TControl;

begin
  inherited;
  if Msg.message = WM_LBUTTONDOWN then
  begin

    ScreenPt := ScreenToClient(Msg.pt);
    DragControl := FindDragTarget(Msg.pt , false);
    if Assigned(DragControl) and
      ((DragControl = MyThingThatDragsIt)
      ) then
    begin
      ReleaseCapture;
      self.Perform(WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MOVE or $0002, 0 );
    end;
  end
end;
```

That works OK, but when I let go, my program has lost it's focus and I've got to click once on the form just to click on any other buttons.

Any idea what is wrong here? I followed [steps from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976610/moving-a-caption-less-window-by-using-a-drag-area)

Comment: Doesn't a simple SetFocus after the call to Perform do the trick?

Comment: @UweRaabe that was among the first 40 VCL commands I tried in vain :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell the VCL that you've taken care of the message:

```
  ...
  Perform(WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MOVE or $0002, 0 );
  Handled := True;
  ...
```