# delphi xe 7 Tlistbox main form loose focus after draganddrop

Tags: drag-and-drop, firemonkey, delphi-xe7, tlistbox

i found a bug in delphi xe7, after a drag and drop TlistBoxitem, form loose over effect on all components.

**I have to click the form to get mouseenter effect**.
i saw (on debug mode) the TlistBox start draganddrop by call os dragAndDrop service's OS. from FMX.ListBox unit

```
if AllowDrag then
      begin
        Screenshot := ItemDown.MakeScreenshot;
        try
          AniCalculations.MouseLeave;
          FMouseSelecting := False;
          // start drag service
          Root.BeginInternalDrag(Selected, Screenshot);
        finally
          Screenshot.Free;
        end;
      end;
```

i tried draganddrop on delphi berlin and the bug is fixed. i can't see the source because it's the light version.

i didn't find any solution in web.

i did a project exemple : http://www.partage-fichiers.com/upload/qgbl1e5g

After drag and drop items mouseenter (on all compenents) and click on Tlabel (hittest=true) is not fired

Comment: i tested the main form don't loose focus and isn't deactivate

Comment: ok sorry i founded a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821670/delphi-window-losing-focus-after-custom-drag?rq=1, but i work in firemonkey i think it's not just a TlistBox's bug

Comment: Hard for us to investigate without a reproduction. Can't we have a [mcve]?

Comment: hi david sorry for my bad post, you can reproduce the bug without coding (only graphic): with delphi xe7 make a form in FMX with a Tbutton and Tlistbox insert sevral TlistBoxItem. After a internal dragAndDrop of a Item, the TButton's mouseEnter is not fired. i write a small code because i isolated the bug at "myListBox.Root.BeginInternalDrag(aItem, Screenshot);" if is not enough i'll post a minimal code        Thank you anyway

Comment: I don't want to have to pfaff around like that. If it takes me effort to help you, I'll do something else.

Comment: is it better or It's still not enough ?

Comment: That doesn't look much like a [mcve]. Did you follow that link and read it carefully?

Comment: i'll post a project test

Comment: Why don't you do what I suggested, and what you claimed earlier to be possible? Make a very small reproduction. We don't need to see all of your code that is unrelated to the behaviour at hand.

Comment: ok i'll reduce my code and i'll clearer

Answer (score 0):

For get mousenter and mouseclick events after

```
BeginInternalDrag(mylistboxItem, Screenshot);
```

Do

```
MyListBox.Root.Captured := nil;
```