# Is it possible to set the Window (x, y) Position in RAD Studio 10 c++?

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder

I'm developing an application and it looks as if my Form object doesn't have anything for me to specify its exact coordinates.

I have a label at the top acting as a titlebar, in c# I could use a combination of my mouse coordinates and window coordinates to make the window move with the mouse when the user clicks and drags. However, in c++ (along side RAD studio) there doesn't appear to be anything online I can use as reference to pull this off.

I've tried windows api with:

```
SetWindowPos(this->GetOwnerWindow(), HWND_TOPMOST, 5,5,5,5, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

There's things like window position, but that only accepts integers or vars like "poScreenCenter".

Any insight on how this could be possible would be great.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into seeing if I can somehow implement that

Comment: Okay, that seems to work! If you leave yours as an answer I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TForm` (and all UI controls in general) have `Left` and `Top` (and `Width` and `Height`) properties.

You can use the Label's `OnMouse(Down|Up)` events to set/unset a bool, and then have the Label's `OnMouseMove` event reposition the Form if the bool is set.

A simpler and more efficient solution is to have the `OnMouseDown` event send an undocumented `WM_COMMAND(SC_DRAGMOVE)` message to the Form's HWND and let the OS handle the rest for you. See [Moving a caption-less window by using a "drag area"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976610/) (written for Delphi, but it applies to C++Builder too, since they use the same VCL framework).

Comment: I've put in my own version already, works perfectly. Thank you for the HQ answer